# Legacy Database Schema - Key/Value Tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a legacy database schema which consists of objects similar to the following:

```
table=car
oid, something, something_else, ...
has many properties -> car_properties

table=car_properties
oid, car_id, keyname, value, ...
belongs to car
```

The Car object is actually (logically) a combination of the columns in the "car" table, and multiple rows in the "car_properties" table.

I'm looking at doing a parallel rewrite of the application which uses this schema, so I need some way to map this table schema back to a nice ActiveRecord object.  Ideally I'd like each of the properties in the _properties table to be accessible as a method on the "Car" class, so I can change the underlying table later without breaking things.

I can statically define the methods in the Car class, but I want to ensure that the ActiveRecord magic works, so things like .save work, and I can change the underlying schema at a later date (realising this will probably be an outage to the application).

How would I go about doing this in ActiveRecord?

To Clarify:

Basically, I want the following to work

```
@car = Car.first
@car.something = something
@car.someprop = something
```

However in the above, `@code.someprop` is actually `@car.properties.where( "keyname = ?", "someprop" ).value`

Obviously I don't want to be doing a SQL Query every time for this though, so I'm looking for a nice way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm underthinking it, it should be something as simple as:

```
class CarProperty < ActiveRecord::Base
   set_primary_key :oid

   belongs_to :car
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
   set_table_name :car
   set_primary_key :oid

   has_many :car_properties

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :car_properties
end
```

Comment: Unless I'm misinterpreting how accepts_nested_attributes_for works, I'm not sure it's quite what I'm after.

Comment: I don't think ActiveRecord is going to help you do that. You could probably accomplish that layer of abstraction with method_missing but you'd probably drive yourself crazy in the process. I'd worry more about the presentation layer. I assume the point is that users have a nice interface for car & car properties?

Comment: Yes, but I'd also like the backend objects to be nice to work with... particularly as we start to refactor the database design (which can't happen until we've done the full port over the space of ~ 3-6 months)